# Getting position and moving robot joint in ros using rosbag and dynamixel

Tags: python-3.x, ros

I'm trying to control the movement of my robot using [dynamixel_workbench](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench) package.
My [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/) version in **noetic** and my motors are **dynamixel Ax12**
I run *dynamixel_workbench_controllers.launch* file and I can see the position of each joint as I move the robot arms (in *joint_states* topic)
I record this topic with rosbag and when I play the bag file I can see that it has recorded the positions (using *rostopic echo /dynamixel_workbench/joint_states*) but the arms dont move accordingly. I mean the bag file is recorded and played correctly but doesnt seem to work with motors.

Can anyone help me with that? What should I do to move the motors with bag file?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't move correctly? How is the bag file being recorded? `rosbag record -a`?

Comment: the motors are still and do not move while the bag file is being played. i use rosbag record /dynamixel_workbench/joint_states...without the -a option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic you're recording is a `Publisher` of the package, not a `Subscriber`. This means what you're recording is feedback from the node saying where it currently is in *response* to a command, you can see on [the package page](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench_controllers). The movement is actually done in response to a `Service` call. Unfortunately, there isn't any way to directly record services via `rosbag`. The best you could do is write a quick node that subscribes to a topic and translates that message into a service call. This would effectively let you control the robot, record the commands, and play them back having the actions repeated(still through the node you wrote).

Comment: yeah i guess thats the problem. thank you. as im not that good in ros, can u guide me how to do that? i know how to write a node that subscribes to the topic, but after that i dont know what to do? i should define a new service/client? there is a topic called **set_position** and it can set the positions of motors (what is want to do) but now it only gets input from the keyboard...i dont know how should i make it get rosbag data instead. ill be thankful if u can help or send me a tutorial related to that

Comment: @shakiba glad it helped, feel free to accept the answer if you think it was appropriately helpful. For services you can see the wiki tutorial here:http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29. If you have more questions from that I would suggest opening a new question here.

Comment: i did that.and thank you i will check it for sure. i know a little about the services...my problem is that i dont know what exactly to do in the node. call the client? use current and ready services? define new ones? use only python to read data? im confused